# What is the guy in the tower outside Yavin IV doing?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, rogue-one

In both A New Hope and Rogue One, there is a guy in a tower with a radar gun looking thing.  He points the device at all incoming and outgoing ships.

What is his purpose and what is he doing?

[image]

Comment: I just like the notion that he's "outside" Yavin IV.

Comment: @Buzz Oops... yeah, I meant outside the temple on Yavin 4.